# Redirect To Action with parameter values within controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, controller

## Scenario

I have an **Auth Controller**, for authorizing user and admin credentials and registering new users. When a user is found to already exist, I want to reroute the controller to an overloaded action that I declare within the controller, passing a string as a Route Value to that action. However, at present, this doesn't appear to be working.

## AuthController.cs

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Registration";

        return View(new RegisterViewModel());
    }

    public IActionResult Register(string caption)
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Registration";

        ViewBag.caption = caption;

        return View(new RegisterViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel vm)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(vm);

        var user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = vm.Email,
            Email    = vm.Email
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password");

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // !> Initial Registration!
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Register", "Auth", "This user is currently configured with a password");
    }
```

## Issue

Presently if I use the following Redirect:

```cs
    return RedirectToAction("Register", "Auth", "This user is currently configured with a password");
```

it goes to the first, or this action:

```cs
    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Registration";

        return View(new RegisterViewModel());
    }
```

rather than the second, or this action:

```cs
    public IActionResult Register(string caption)
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Registration";

        ViewBag.caption = caption;

        return View(new RegisterViewModel());
    }
```

Not quite sure whether I'm approaching this issue correctly. Any opinions or advice would surely be appreciated.

Comment: You are doing a redirect, so you are making a GET request which is why it is calling the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is wrong:

```cs
return RedirectToAction("Register", "Auth", "This user is currently configured with a password");
```

You need to supply an object containing the parameters, not a string.
A string is only for defining an url fragment (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Can you try:

```cs
return RedirectToAction("Register", "Auth", new { caption = "This user is currently configured with a password"});
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You may try this below syntax ::

[RedirectToAction with parameter]

return RedirectToAction ("Action","controller",new {@id=id});

Answer (score 0):

You could custom `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` like below:

```
public class RequireRequestValueAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public RequireRequestValueAttribute(string valueName)
    {
        ValueName = valueName;
    }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
    {
        bool contains = false;
        contains = routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey(ValueName);   
        return contains;
    }

    public string ValueName { get; private set; }
}
```

For testing:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpGet]
[RequireRequestValue("caption")]
public IActionResult Register(string caption)
{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Registration";

    ViewBag.caption = caption;

    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account", new { caption = "This user is currently configured with a password" });
}
```